# can any one guide me how to upgrade my fastai library

Tags: python, fast-ai, imagelist

conda -c fastai fastai=1.0.46

File "", line 1
conda -c fastai fastai=1.0.46
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Looks like you entered the command at the Python REPL instead of the OS shell.

Comment: no i entered in OS  shell